# Unity3D Animator Conditions - when do the transition starts?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

Iv a simple character with animations on it, and Mecanim animation controller for it. Transitions in that controller uses the conditions. There are more than one condition in all of the transitions iv got. So the question is, when the particular transition will start? Have the conditions to be set all together to start the transition, or one of them will be enough for transition start? And can i change this behavior somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If there is at least one transition between two state, the transition will start immediately when condition change.
2. Conditions that are in one transition are AND operator